# Transferring values from a json-string into an object-instance in nim

Tags: object-oriented, json, nim

While writing a web application I've stumbled upon the following problem:

I have a relational database. For each table with `n` columns I have an object-type (called model-object, think ORM) with identically named `n` fields. Any records queried from a table are converted into such object types.

If these are updated by a user via HTTP-PATCH request, the request is structured so that the request-body I receive contains *only* the key-value pairs of the column-names (and thus fieldnames on a given model-object) that I want to update and their future values. Then as you would expect from a PATCH request, the only fields that change are the ones that are being sent. Here an image of how I would expect that to work (Note how only the "description" field is sent and thus changes. Also Note how I'm also dealing with Optionals potentially):

[image]

Overall, I'm dealing with values that are either `int`, `int64`, `string`, `float`, `bool` or `DateTime`.

I've managed to solve this through copious amounts of templates and generic procs in a generic manner so far.

My solution algorithm looks like this:

1. Parse String into a `JsonNode` object, which is basically a bunch of key-value pairs
2. Iterate over all fields in the model-type and check if the `JsonNode` object contains a key with the same name as a given model-field
3. If the JSON contains such a key, extract the `JsonNode`-object that represents that key-value pair (further called "valueNode")
4. Check which type the model-field is supposed to have and what `JsonNodeKind` the "valueNode" has.
5. If the `JsonNodeKind` indicates that the value in "valueNode" can be converted into the model-field's type, then extract the value out of the "valueNode" and copy it into the modelField. If a type-conversion needs to happen somewhere, then do so.

This has to essentially cover every combination of `JsonNodeKind` and field-type that I can expect to deal with, and raise runtime-Exceptions if I'm facing an "invalid combination" of model-field-type and `JsonNodeKind` (e.g. a JNull kind aka a "null" value in the json for a model-field that must not be null, or a JString kind for a model-field that is supposed to be a number).

The code for this solution looks like this (The core proc is `updateEntryWithJson`, everything else is just a helper to generate the desired expression):

```
## ACTUAL CODE START

import std/[strformat, options, json, strutils, typetraits, macros]

type Parseable = int | int64 | string | float | bool

macro getField*(obj: ref object, fieldName: static string): untyped =
  ## Generates at compile-time the expression `obj.fieldName` with whatever 
  ## string is within `fieldName`
  nnkDotExpr.newTree(obj, ident(fieldName))

template transferJsonIntValue(receiver: var Option[int], valueNode: JsonNode) =
  case valueNode.kind:
  of JsonNodeKind.JInt:
    receiver = some(valueNode.num.int)
  else:
    raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have an int-type, but the json was of kind '{valueNode.kind}'")

template transferJsonInt64Value(receiver: var Option[int64], valueNode: JsonNode) =
  case valueNode.kind:
  of JsonNodeKind.JInt:
    receiver = some(valueNode.num)
  else:
    raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have an int64-type, but the json was of kind '{valueNode.kind}'")

template transferJsonStringValue(receiver: var Option[string], valueNode: JsonNode) =
  case valueNode.kind:
  of JsonNodeKind.JString:
    receiver = some(valueNode.str)
  else:
    raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have a string-type, but the json was of kind '{valueNode.kind}'")

template transferJsonBoolValue(receiver: var Option[bool], valueNode: JsonNode) =
  case valueNode.kind:
  of JsonNodeKind.JBool:
    receiver = some(valueNode.bval)
  of JsonNodeKind.JInt:
    if valueNode.num in 0..1:
      receiver = some(valueNode.num.bool)
    else:
      raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have a boolean-type or an int-value between 0 and 1. An int-value {valueNode.num} was received, but it was outside of that range!")

  else:
    raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have a boolean-type, but the json was of kind '{valueNode.kind}'")


template transferFloatValue(receiver: var Option[float], node: JsonNode) =
  case node.kind:
  of JsonNodeKind.JFloat:
    receiver = some(node.fnum)
  of JsonNodeKind.JInt:
    receiver = some(node.num.float)
  else:
    raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have a float-type, but the json {%*value} was of kind '{valueNode.kind}'")


template moveValueIntoField[M: ref object](entry: var M, fieldName: static string, value: Option[Parseable]) =
  when entry.getField(fieldName).type() is Option:
    entry.getField(fieldName) = value
  else:
    if value.isSome():
      entry.getField(fieldName) = value.get()
    else:
      raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"The field {typeName}.{fieldName} expected the json to have a value. But there was no value")



proc transferJsonValue[M: ref object](entry: var M, fieldName: static string, fieldType: typedesc[Parseable], valueNode: JsonNode) =
  ## Takes the field `fieldName` on `entry` that has the type `fieldType` and transfers 
  ## the value from within `valueNode` into it. If necessary, the type of the value in
  ## `valueNode` will be converted to `fieldType`, should that operation be supported.
  var value: Option[fieldType]
  const typeName = name(M)

  if valueNode.kind == JsonNodeKind.JNull:
    when entry.getField(fieldName) is Option:
      value = none(fieldType)
    else:
      raise newException(JsonParsingError, fmt"Attempted to set the field {typeName}.{fieldName} to null, but it is not an optional type!")

  else:
    when fieldType is int:
      transferJsonIntValue(value, valueNode)
    
    elif fieldType is int64:
      transferJsonInt64Value(value, valueNode)

    elif fieldType is string:
      transferJsonStringValue(value, valueNode)

    elif fieldType is bool:
      transferJsonBoolValue(value, valueNode)
      
    elif fieldType is float:
      transferFloatValue(value, valueNode)
  
  moveValueIntoField(entry, fieldName, value)

proc updateEntryWithJson*[T: ref object](entry: var T, jsonString: string) =
  let json: JsonNode = jsonString.parseJson()
  for fieldName, fieldValue in T()[].fieldPairs:
    if json.hasKey(fieldName):
      when fieldValue is Option:
        transferJsonValue(entry, fieldName, genericParams(fieldValue.type()).get(0), json[fieldName])
      else:
        transferJsonValue(entry, fieldName, fieldValue.type(), json[fieldName])


## ACTUAL CODE END

## TEST-EXAMPLE START

type Creature* = ref object
    s1*: string
    s2*: Option[string]
    n1*: int
    n2*: Option[int]
    n3*: int64
    n4*: Option[int64]
    f1*: float
    f2*: Option[float]
    b1*: bool
    b2*: Option[bool]


var wolf = Creature(s1: "s1", s2: some("s2"), n1: 1, n2: some(1), n3: 2, n4: some(2.int64), f1: 3.0, f2: some(3.0), b1: true, b2: some(true))

let jsonStr: string = """ {"s1":"super", "s2": "super", "n1": -4, "n2": -5, "n3": -6, "n4": -7, "f1": -8.2, "f2": -9.2, "b1": false, "b2": false} """
updateEntryWithJson(wolf, jsonStr)
echo %*wolf

let jsonStr2: string = """ {"s1":"super", "s2": null, "n1": -4, "n2": null, "n3": -6, "n4": null, "f1": -8.2, "f2": null, "b1": 1, "b2": 0} """
updateEntryWithJson(wolf, jsonStr2)
echo %*wolf
echo wolf.s2.isNone()

## TEST-EXAMPLE END
```

My problems with that code are mostly concerning readability.

Despite my cleaning it up by splitting things into smaller templates, it is still not easy to read in my opinion. I'm also using some magic, like how the templates are assuming that they'll be used in a context where the `typeName` and `fieldName` variables are defined for better error-messages. This is done in order to keep the actual call to the templates free of those parameters since in terms of encapsulating knowledge they really shouldn't know of those parameters... yet I do so anyway because otherwise my error-messages become significantly less informative.

This is a bit of a mess, but given my general difficulty in dealing with compile-time mechanisms (such as macros and templates), I'm struggling to see further ways to clean this up while using less magic and without sacrificing informative error messages.